# changing padding between columns in bootstrap 4 ( by a variable if possible)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, twitter-bootstrap-4

I want to change the padding (`left/right`) on columns in Bootstrap 4.

e.g.

`col-md-4`   ( seems to be `15px` padding left and right ), I'd like to make this smaller say `10px`

I've looked in `_variables.scss` but can't see anything, that looks like it might do it.

Comment: change in the `gutter-width` which are used for generated   padding 
 left and right of columns... check this link--https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#columns-and-gutters

Comment: thanks @Minal Chauhan , excellent !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find it in the file 'scss/_variables.scss' on line 205.

```
$grid-gutter-width: 30px !default;
```

You can change '30px' to your desired value or variable.

Comment: Better to override this variable in own variable sheet, instead of changing original file.